# How can I loop through all the xls files in a folder to find the sheet names, and then replace them

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlrd

I am trying to loop through all the XLS files in a folder, and then replace the worksheet name by another string. This has to be done for all the files inside.

I am relatively new to programming, and here is my Python code. It runs okay (partially, when I do it for one file at a time), however, I am unable to get it to work for all the files in the folder.

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook

# open the file
direc = input('Enter file name: ')
rb = open_workbook(direc)

wb = copy(rb)

#index of a sheet
pointSheet = rb.sheet_names()
print(pointSheet)
idx = pointSheet.index(pointSheet)

wb.get_sheet(idx).name = u'RenamedSheet1'
wb.save(direc)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Rename.py", line 13, in <module>
    idx = pointSheet.index(pointSheet)
ValueError: ['x xxx xxxx xxxxxx'] is not in list
```

My bad! The above code is for testing with a single file. Here is the loop:

```
files = []
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('D:\Temp\Final'):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        files.append(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))


pprint(files)

for i in range(0,len(files)):
    rb = open_workbook(files[i])
    wb = copy(rb)
    idx = rb.sheet_names().index('5 new bulk rename')
    wb.get_sheet(idx).name = u'RenamedSheet1'
    wb.save(files[i])

print('Operation succeeded!')
```

Comment: This code doesn't contain a loop? And I don't know how the `.index` function works, but I assume that `.sheet_names()` returns an array of names, and that you need to loop through that array to rename the seperate sheets.

Comment: I think because you're passing an array instead of a string into the `index` function is why the errors says `['x xxx xxxx xxxxxx']` instead of just `'x xxx xxxx xxxxxx'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (untested) for a single file:

```py
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook

# open the file
direc = input('Enter file name: ')
rb = open_workbook(direc)

wb = copy(rb)

for pointSheet in rb.sheet_names()
  print(pointSheet)
  idx = pointSheet.index(pointSheet)
  wb.get_sheet(idx).name = u'RenamedSheet1'
wb.save(direc)
```

And wrap that in another loop using `listdir` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)):

```py
import os
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".xls"):
        # <do what you did for a single file>
```